# 13.8v from transformer

Tags: ac

I have an old CB that looks like the Kraco 2555FM and that takes 13.8v. I'm not sure for certain but that is what I can gather from searching the internet. I guess my CB does take 13.8v as well.  I dont know how many amps it needs but I think 5 amp will be enough.
As for now, I'm running the CB on 12v batteries.

I dont have the original transformer. It blew for many years ago and I removed it in hope I found a new one, but didnt and the CB was put aside. Now many years after I found it in my basement and want to mend it. It nags me that I didnt keep the transformer but well its gone.
I found an old transformer with 2x6v 4.8A. I thought I could use it. But it needs to deliver 13.8v.

So is that possible to get more volts out of the transformer or would it be better to put a dc-dc voltage booster after the bridge rectifier?

Comment: Frank - You need to provide a bit more data. You make it sound like you are trying to see if some alternate transformer will work but you have provided no information about it. As it stands your question is completely unanswerable.

Comment: You are also asking about rectification and regulation which makes it look like you need DC and not AC. Explain the end result and you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Welcome to ee.se. Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions. What is "the unit"? Please post a link to it or its datasheet. Have you already got a transformer? Please post a link to it or its datasheet. As people have said, explain what you are trying to do, so we can help. Your current question is so vague that it will likely get closed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get 13.8v from it by I connect to a winding closer to the core?

Transformer output voltage depends on the input voltage and the turns ratio, not the distance from the core.

> Or will I have to build my own rectifier and step up the voltage or just put a voltage regulator on the output of the build in rectifier and set it to 13.8?

When you rectify the AC signal you will get a peak voltage of \$ \sqrt 2 \$ times the AC voltage.

---

Update

Right, you have a CB radio designed for a 12 V vehicle electrical system. That means it will probably work fine between 11 V (engine off and slightly tired battery) and 14.5 V (engine running and battery charging) DC (direct current). This means that you need a *nominal* 12 V DC power supply. Your estimate of 5 A is probably about right but it would be worth while to take a measurement to check. Switch your multimeter to 10 A DC range, check the leads are in the right sockets - usually 10A and COM - and connect in series between the car battery and the CB. Hold the transmit key and check peak current draw to within an amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNl8zh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. PSU current measurement setup.*

You can then either:

- Purchase a 12 V DC supply with a current rating a bit higher than required to give a safety margin. CB seems to be gaining popularity again so they're readily available on the web.
- Get a used car battery and a small float charger. Set the charger to 'LOW' or 'FLOAT' so you don't boil the battery and run on that. This has the advantage that you have a UPS and can at least have some CB entertainment as you sit in the dark during power cuts.

Don't forget the fuse! Next size up from your measured current should be fine. Your auto-spares shop will have a simple in-line version that will be easy to wire up.